# Problems with _cdecl using indirect recursion

Tags: assembly, cdecl

I've written a factorial computation program that works up until the final computations. When it is calculating the factorial value in `_multiply_fact`, the base pointer ends up pointing to a random value. What am I doing wrong?

Calling

```
push n
call _factorial
add esp, 4
```

The Procedures

```
_factorial:
    push ebp            ;save base pointer
    mov ebp, esp        ;set up new base pointer
    mov ebx, 8[ebp]

    cmp ebx, 1          ;while n > 0
    jg _multiply_fact   ;decrement n
    mov eax, 1          ;if n == 0 ret 1
    pop ebp
    ret                 ;return to multipy_fact for calculation

_multiply_fact:
    pop ebp     
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    mov ebx, 8[ebp]

    dec ebx                 ;decrements n-1 times
    push ebx
    call _factorial 

    inc ebx                 
    mul ebx                 ;recursively multiplies eax * (n+1)
    pop ebp
    ret
```

Answer (score 1):

As you say, the bug that was stopping it from working was lack of fixing the stack after the recursive call.  But **that wasn't the only bug**

`_multiply_fact` is not really a function.  It's just part of `_factorial`'s code, which runs when you don't take the early-out `n <= 1` return path.  So you should *not* be making a stack frame in it.

**The `pop ebp` at the top of `_multiply_fact` is totally bogus**.  It *only* works because the top of the stack when that runs already has the caller's `ebp`.  If you called it directly as a function, you'd clobber the caller's `ebp` with the return address.

First of all, you don't need to make a stack frame at all, so it's just a total waste of stack space and instructions.  (Although it does help debuggers do backtraces, since without it they need info that compilers normally add, but hand-written asm functions don't have unless you add it manually.)

Your `_factorial` also clobbers the caller's `ebx`, which violates the ABI.  I don't think your function will actually get the right value, since it depends on `ebx` surviving across the call to `_factorial`.  After all the recursive calls return, `ebx=1`, because each nested call clobbers ebx with its arg.

Since you're writing in asm, though, you can have your recursive self-calls make assumptions about which registers aren't clobbered, or even pass args in regs if you want.  You still need to save `n` across the recursive call somehow, though.  One option is to take advantage of the fact that you know `_factorial` doesn't clobber its arg on the stack (even though the ABI allows it to).

You still need the publicly accessible wrapper function to follow the ABI, though.

Obviously recursion is a big waste of time for factorial in the first place, compare to a loop, but here's a version that sucks as little as possible.

```
global _factorial
_factorial:
    ; one arg:  int n

    push  ebp
    mov   ebp, esp        ; make a stack frame

    mov   edx, [ebp + 8]  ; load first arg into a scratch reg
    dec   edx
    jg .multiply_fact     ; if ((n-1) > 0).  Note that dec doesn't set CF, so just use jnz instead of ja if you want to convert this to unsigned

    ;; base case
    mov   eax, 1          ;if (n <= 1) ret 1
    pop   ebp
    ret

.multiply_fact:   ; not a separate function, still part of _factorial
                  ; in NASM, .labels are local labels that don't show up as symbols in the object file.  MASM uses something different.
    ; at this point:  edx = n-1

    push  edx
    call  _factorial     ; eax = fac(n-1)
    pop   edx            ; get n-1 back off the stack.  Taking advantage of extra knowledge of our own internals, since the ABI allows functions to clobber their args on the stack
    ; add esp, 4  not needed, because we popped instead

    inc   edx            ; undo the earlier dec before we pushed
    imul  eax, edx       ; n * fac(n-1).  2-arg imul runs faster
    pop ebp
    ret
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright after a little bit more troubleshooting I found that the error was caused because I forgot to include

```
add esp, 4
```

after my call _factorial in the _multiply_fact procedure